# TableLayoutPanel with Horizontal Scrollbar and Child Layout Behavior Unexplained

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am seeing weird behavior in a TableLayoutPanel that I am trying to use as a vertically stacked panel (no horizontal scroll bar, only vertical).

I have setup here a TableLayoutPanel docked to the right of a Form. I removed the extra row and column styles that are created by default. The column style size type will be percent (100%). The row style size types will be AutoSize. I've set AutoScroll to true, and CellBorderStyle to Single because this issue only happens when this property is set.

Here is the relevant code for the buttons:

```
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = new Panel();

    p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p);
}

private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
    } while (this.tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible);
}
```

And here are pictures explaining the issue.

**Picture 1** - I've clicked Button1 once, adding a single fully docked Panel to the TableLayoutPanel.

[image: TableLayoutPanel_1]

**Picture 2** - I've clicked Button1 four more times, getting 5 fully docked Panels and causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear. At this point, I don't understand why the vertical scroll bar appearing hasn't shifted over the docked Panels so that there is no horizontal scroll bar.

[image: TableLayoutPanel_2]

**Picture 3** - I've clicked Button2 once, causing that loop to run where, oddly, every PerformLayout call decreases the docked panel's width by 1, eventually causing the horizonal scroll bar to go away.

[image: TableLayoutPanel_3]

**Questions**

1. Why, when I add the fifth Panel, does the horizontal scroll bar appear? Every Panel is docked, so I don't understand why when the vertical scroll bar appears it doesn't cause the Panels width to decrease by the vertical scroll bar width (like a docked panel should behave).
2. What is going on with the layout engine that is causing it to decrease the width's by 1 after every PeformLayout call? My suspicion is that it is a bug relating to the CellBorderStyle property being set to Single.
3. My third, and actually the most important question for myself is: What is the best way to get a reliable, vertically stacked panel where there is 1 control per row, and its size is completely dependent on the width of the parent container? The solution should at no point have a horizontal scroll bar appear. Preferably an out of the box type solution (no custom controls).

Comment: Does the _second_ panel you add remain quite large, vertically?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Yup, it keeps filling until the fifth panel.

Comment: I can reproduce it, but other than putting your _button2_ code after every panel addition, I can't figure a way to beat it.  And I agree, it's related to the border type.

Comment: At least if you use `tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();` prior to adding anything, you can get them all to add at the same size.

Comment: The layout you asked for is bi-stable.  Caused by the scrollbars taking away available layout space.  There is no decent fix for this, it cannot be solved by forcing multiple layout passes.  You'll have to calculate the panel size yourself.